# JSP import Java class

Tags: java, jsp, import

When I try to call the method after importing the class, like below, I get method is undefined error.

```
<%@page import="td.TourHelper"%>
<%=getTourName()%>
```

But, when I directly call the method, it works.

```
<%=td.TourHelper.getTourName()%>
```

Any clues?

Comment: I get nervous when JSPs import things--it's likely the code belongs in a servlet/framework class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<%=getTourName()%>
```

to

```
<%=TourHelper.getTourName()%>
```

The first option will work if your container supports [static imports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) provided you change the page directive as below

```
<%@page import="static td.TourHelper"%>
```